# Splitting a list into two lists based on its types of elements? Distinguishing numbers and strings elements of lists in two different lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I want to change `['123', '213', 'acd', '321', 'dac']` to `[['123', '321', '213'], ['acd', 'dac']]` in python 3.X.

Comment: There are no tuples here... Also, all the elements in your list are of the same type...

Comment: There are no tuples there, just lists of all strings.

Comment: I am wondering to split based on string character and numberical one!

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what your difficulty is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Comment: @juanpa-arrivillaga All of data are the same types a list made of characters elements and numbering elements! I want to separate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the simplest way to reach what you want:

```
arr = ['123', '213', 'acd', '321', 'dac']

new_arr = [[], []]
for element in arr:
    try:
        new_arr[0].append(int(element))
    except ValueError:
        new_arr[1].append(element)


print(new_arr)
```

Comment: The question is not clear on type limits or how this is going to be used, but my suggestion would be to attempt a cast to `decimal.Decimal` rather than `int`. That way floats are supported. I think the exception to catch would be `decimal.InvalidOperation` in that case.

Comment: @kungphu Your suggestion is a valid one. However, I think the question is minimal, hence, answers are limited to the presented examples. Else, the cases to be handled would be much more than your suggestion.

Comment: That's one way to look at it... I tend to add whatever I consider relevant and potentially useful, since someone asking a question like this will probably benefit from further explanation and detail on likely future issues and/or helpful language features.

Comment: @kungphu suggest an edit, and I will approve it, just to honor your suggestion.